# How to force looplifting in Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to implement a Numba-compiled version of `numpy.take()`, but I'm very confused by Numba.

Firstly, as I understand it's not possible to create a new `ndarray` inside a numba function in `nopython` mode. Current version of the docs doesn't seem to mention it anywhere, but I was able to find it in [old Numba v0.15 docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/arrays.html). So I have to abandon `nopython` mode.

Secondly, I don't understand how looplifting works, at least with my tests. Here is my code:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import time

@jit(forceobj = True)
def _take1(arr, idxs):
    res = np.ndarray((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    lastIdx = arr.size - 1
    for i in range(idxs.size):
        idx = idxs[i]
        if idx > lastIdx:
            idx = lastIdx
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = 0
        res[i] = arr[idx]
    return res

def _take2(arr, idxs):
    res = np.ndarray((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    lastIdx = arr.size - 1
    for i in range(idxs.size):
        idx = idxs[i]
        if idx > lastIdx:
            idx = lastIdx
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = 0
        res[i] = arr[idx]
    return res

sz = 2000000
arr = np.arange(sz, dtype = np.int32)
idxs = np.arange(sz, 0, -1, dtype = np.int32)

start = time.time()
_take2(arr, idxs)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (plain python)      = %s" % (end - start))

start = time.time()
_take1(arr, idxs)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation)  = %s" % (end - start))

start = time.time()
_take1(arr, idxs)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (after compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
```

This code gives the following output on my laptop:

```
Elapsed (plain python)      = 0.8870017528533936
Elapsed (with compilation)  = 1.7350387573242188
Elapsed (after compilation) = 1.1779978275299072
```

So the compiled version is slower than pure python. My guess is that it's because it doesn't use "looplifting" and I can't find a way to enable it. On the other hand, the [5-minute guide](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode) states about the object mode:

> In this mode Numba will identify loops that it can compile and compile those into functions that run in machine code, and it will run the rest of the code in the interpreter

But there is a catch. If I remove `(forceobj = True)` from the 5th line (leaving just `@jit`) I get the following output:

```
Elapsed (plain python)      = 0.88104248046875
c:\[path-to-my-folder]\test.py:6: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "_take1" failed type inference due to: Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.ndarray' or unsupported use of the function.

File "test.py", line 8:
def _take1(arr, idxs):
    res = np.ndarray((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    ^

During: typing of get attribute at c:\[path-to-my-folder]\test.py (8)

File "test.py", line 8:
def _take1(arr, idxs):
    res = np.ndarray((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    ^

  @jit

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
C:\[path-to-my-python]\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:161: NumbaDeprecationWarning:
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "test.py", line 8:
def _take1(arr, idxs):
    res = np.ndarray((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    ^
  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
Elapsed (with compilation)  = 0.4593193531036377
Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.0029413700103759766
```

So now the compiled version of the function is drastically faster than pure python even though numba is still clearly in object mode. What is suspicious to me is `object mode WITH looplifting enabled` in the warning text. It looks like there could also be an object mode without looplifting.

To summarize, I have 3 questions:

1. Is it true that I can not create a new `ndarray` with Numba in `nopython` mode?
2. Why does `@jit` with fallback to object mode works a lot faster than `@jit(forceobj = True)`?
3. Is there an object mode without looplifting in Numba? And if so, what is its purpose?

Thank you!

Comment: What is supposed to be "looplifting" precisely? The Numba documentation is very unclear about this.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Here's a link to the glossary: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-loop-lifting
It states the following:
A feature of compilation in object mode where a loop can be automatically extracted and compiled in nopython mode. This allows functions with operations unsupported in nopython mode to see significant performance improvements if they contain loops with only nopython-supported operations.

Comment: "Firstly, as I understand it's not possible to create a new ndarray inside a numba function in nopython mode." That is not correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it true that I can not create a new ndarray with Numba in nopython mode?

This is **wrong**. The following working code does that:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int32[:](int32)')
def example(n):
    res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(n):
        res[i] = i
    return res

example(4)  # output: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

> Why does @jit with fallback to object mode works a lot faster than @jit(forceobj = True)?

You should **avoid the object mode like the plague**. It is generally very inefficient and often not really useful unless you deals with Python objects which are slow to compute due to the GIL, reference counting, allocations, dynamic-typing and many performance issues that makes CPython slow. The [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/performance-tips.html) states:

> Whilst the use of looplifting in object mode can enable some performance increase, getting functions to compile under **no python mode** is really the key to good performance.

Moreover, it [also states](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html):

> `forceobj` forces the function to be compiled in object mode. Since object mode is slower than nopython mode, this is mostly useful for testing purposes.

Thus, the challenge is to make your code build with the `njit` mode. In your case this is simple: you just need to use `np.empty` and `njit`.

```py
@njit
def _take1(arr, idxs):
    res = np.empty((idxs.size,), arr.dtype)
    lastIdx = arr.size - 1
    for i in range(idxs.size):
        idx = idxs[i]
        if idx > lastIdx:
            idx = lastIdx
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = 0
        res[i] = arr[idx]
    return res
```

This make the code much master on my machine:

```
Elapsed (plain python)      = 3.343827962875366
Elapsed (with compilation)  = 0.06859207153320312
Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.00159454345703125
```

Note that you can provide the signature of `_take1` so Numba can compile it [eagerly](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html?highlight=lazy#lazy-compilation).

> Is there an object mode without looplifting in Numba? And if so, what is its purpose?

The purpose of the object mode is simply the compatibility with pure-Python code. This is useful when a Numba code is mixed with pure-Python functions. The pure-Python function call will be slow but at least Numba can call them in the middle of a Numba code. The object mode is often not very useful in optimized Numba codes, and if you use it, then you generally need the looplifting so to boost the performance of hot loops. Otherwise, using Numba is certainly not very useful in the target case (rare exceptions include wrapping codes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, his solves my problem! But I'm still curious why is there a drastic difference between @jit with a fallback and @jit(forceobj=True)...

Comment: I added a note in the answer about this. Put it shortly, `forceobj` should not be used in production as it generates a slow code. It is only meant to be used for testing/debugging purposes based on the docuementaion.